# Geometric proof or interpretation of the triple tangent and cotangent identities

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, alternative-proof, plane-geometry

The not-so-well-known [triple tangent and triple cotangent identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Other_related_identities),

> If $x + y + z = \pi$ then $\tan x + \tan y + \tan z = \tan x\tan y\tan z 
>  \;\;\; (x,y,z \neq \pi/2+\pi n)$.
>
> If $x + y + z = \frac\pi 2$ then $\cot x + \cot y + \cot z = \cot x \cot y \cot z \;\;\; (x,y,z \neq \pi n)$.

are usually proved analytically. Are there geometric proofs of these identities? Or at least geometric interpretations that might provide some intuition for why they are true?

Comment: I don't know if there is a geometric way to show this, but I'll leave an algebraic solution: https://www.askiitians.com/forums/Trigonometry/if-x-y-z-pi-prove-cotx-2-coty-2-cotx-2-cotx-2_254179.htm

Comment: @Prometheus - Thanks. There are plenty of analytic proofs floating around the web, including a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_trigonometric_identities#Miscellaneous_%E2%80%93_the_triple_tangent_identity) with proofs of these and many other trig identities. It has a nice geometric proof of the angle sum identities for sine and cosine, but unfortunately nothing like that for the identities I asked about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: trigonograph]

> Let $AF=\tan\theta$. Then, obtain expressions for $AE, EF, EC, EB, BC, FD,$ and $DC$ in order.

> $\implies AD=BC \;\; \blacksquare$

[image: trigonograph for cot]

> Similarly, let $FD=\cot\theta$, and let the magic happen...

Comment: Nice! This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. I'm going to try to use it as inspiration to try developing a geometric proof of the cotangent identity as well. Unless you have that one hanging around as well?

Comment: @TedHopp I have also added a diagram for cotangent, hope you like it.

Comment: Thanks again. I hadn't had a chance to try my hand at a proof, and now I don't need to. :)